# Can we include/import XLIFF file into another XLIFF file?

Tags: xliff

If I want to divide translation file into sub modules, how I can merge it into one file (which path is provided)?

Answer (score 0):

Depends what type of tool you use. But generally yes. With SDL Trados that is possible. But the XLIFF they generate is not exactly 100% like the standard.

The big question is, why would you?